# SQL Am I using this join correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using a university relation (students are advised by instructors in different departments, only one advisor per student but advisors can have zero to many advisees), I'm attempting to write a function that computes the total number of students being advised in a given department.

Here are the tables and columns for reference:

```
student(id,name,dept_name,tot_cred)
instructor(id,name,dept_name, salary)
advisor(s_id,i_id)
```

I already know how to use delimiter and such so no I don't need to be told how to write a function. I'm just having issues getting what I want from the select statement alone.

This is the best I've been able to come up with so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM advisor 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN instructor 
ON i_id=id 
ORDER BY dept_name;
```

This statement yields:

[image: This statement yields a joined table containing both student and instructor ids organized by dept_name]

Is there a way I can write an if statement or some other statement to delete all of the NULL entries and then use a count function (within the custom function I'll be writing) that will count the number of instances dept_name occurs, resulting in the total number of advisees per department?

Comment: We typically re-order the tables so that it's a LEFT join, with the "driving" table on the left. (There's nothing wrong with having the driving table on the right and doing a RIGHT JOIN; but since we can do it either way, we typically opt for LEFT JOIN form. Also, best practice is to qualify all column references in a query; normally we use a short alias, maybe an `i` for instructor and `a` for advisor, and we qualify column references with the alias `a.dept_name`, and `a.i_id=i.id` (prevents ambiguous column errors cropping up when column is added to a table, and makes sql easier to decipher.

Comment: Change the SELECT list from `*` to **`i.dept_name, COUNT(a.s_id)`** and replace the **`ORDER BY dept_name`** with a **`GROUP BY i.dept_name`**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I actually feel like I understand joins better now and I didn't even realize that there was a huge difference between group by and order by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i.dept_name, COUNT(a.s_id)
FROM Instructor i
    LEFT JOIN advisor a ON i.id = a.i_id
GROUP BY i.dept_name;
```

This will include zeros for departments with no advisees.

Comment: This just gives me the number of students being advised in total and attributes them all to the art department which is untrue

Comment: Ah yes, I missed a `GROUP BY`.  I think your accepted answer won't return zeros if there are no students being advised in a department, so you might want to double-check.

Comment: Hm... now when I try this I get all of the departments listed but the count column is doing something weird. I think there's an issue with the sum function. Why use sum instead of count?

Comment: +1. This returns the specified result, although the alias for the expression should be enclosed in backticks, rather than single quotes, or be changed to a non-reserved word. Also, a simpler aggregate expression would return the same result **`COUNT(a.s_id)`**.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593, updated with your suggestions.  I wasn't sure if `COUNT(a.s_id)` would count `NULL` rows or not, but obviously you are correct, it doesn't, and the count is correct using your method. +1 on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the number of advised students per *student* department then:

```
SELECT s.dept_name, COUNT(a.s_id)
FROM      student s
LEFT JOIN advisor a ON a.s_id=s.id
GROUP BY s.dept_name
```

OTOH, if you are interested in the number of advised students per *instructor* department then:

```
SELECT i.dept_name, COUNT(a.s_id)
FROM      instructor i
LEFT JOIN advisor    a ON a.i_id=i.id
GROUP BY i.dept_name
```

Comment: Whether or not this is correct depends on exactly what you've been asked to do. The question says "students are advised by instructors in different departments" and asks for "the total number of advisees per department". The last part is kind of ambiguous - it could be interpreted as "advisees per student department" or it could be "advisees per instructor department". Personally, I would suspect the latter - which would need need the `instructor` table.

Comment: I just realized though that it still isn't counting correctly. The art and finance departments should have two advisees. I think the statement still isn't accounting for students who may be advised by other departments.

Comment: To echo Andrew's comment: this query in this answer returns the department of the student, **not** the department of the **instructor**. (Not sure why this is the selected answer, since it doesn't return the result as I understood the specification.)

Comment: The specs state "number of students being advised in a given department". I understood it to be the student's department.

Comment: Excuse me Christina... why should the Finance department have 2 adivisees? From the data you show it would seem to have 2 students, 1 of which has no advisor. Am I correct?

Comment: Oops sorry frazz, you're right. But the art department still should have two students in it. I got so excited that it initially worked that I failed to manually count the students being advised in each department to make sure the query was true. After going back and reviewing my initial thought process I agree with Andrew and spencer7593 that I need the instructor information rather than the student's.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you need:

```
SELECT i.dept_name, COUNT(a.s_id) FROM instructor i
LEFT OUTER JOIN advisor a ON i.id = a.i_id
GROUP BY i.dept_name;
```

I have to add that `advisor(s_id,i_id)` is bad database design if a student really can not have more than 1 advisor as you said. Because in that case, simply add advisor_id to the student relation and get rid of the advisor table.

Also: your use of the word 'function' is incorrect. We are talking about queries here.

Comment: I'm not looking for the total number of students associated with a given department. I'm trying to find the number of students being advised in each department. I just realized that I forgot that tidbit of information above so it's been added. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can a student have an advisor from a different department? Can a student have multiple advisors for multiple departments? Is the dept_name on the student table pretty much meaningless for this problem?

Comment: The dept_name in the student table is referring to their major.A student can have an advisor from a different department but they can only have one advisor.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this:

```
SELECT i.dept_name, COUNT(s.*) AS totalAdvisedNum 
FROM student s, advisor a, instructor i
WHERE a.s_id = s.id AND a.i_id = i.id GROUP BY i.dept_name
```

This will select the department name and total number of students being advised by instructors in these departments

If you need to get the number for a specific department you should replace **GROUP BY i.dept_name** with AND **i.dept_name = "name of department"**